# How to change user password in karaf console?

Tags: apache-karaf

I'm following the security guide for apache karaf: https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/security

I've learned how to add a new user or remove existing one. However, I've failed to find out, how to change the password of existing user. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention which bundle version you are using.

Try this.Hope this works

```
$SMX$_HOME/system/org/apache/felix/karaf/apache-felix-karaf/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/apache-felix-karaf-1.4.0-fuse-02-00-features.xml
```

There's a webconsole feature in this file, where you can reset username/password.